# Angular2. Can't set class property

Tags: angular

I begin learning of angular2 and I have a problem.
There is some class

```
export class UserComponent {
  user: User;
  errorMessage: string;

  constructor(
     private usersService: UsersService,
     private route: ActivatedRoute
  ) {
     let id = +route.params._value.id;
     this.usersService.getUser(id).subscribe(
        user => this.user = user,
        error => this.errorMessage = <any>error
     );
  console.log(this);
}
```

I can see property "user" in console, but not "errorMessage".
http://screen.mindklab.com/incoming/82c673e18ae8f89d7c6175a57c33.png

If I change console.log(this) to console.log(this.user) I get "undefined" in console. Why class' own property doesn't changed?
Because of this I can't use "user" in template

this is service class:

```
@Injectable()
export class UsersService {
private usersUrl = 'http://gye.hz/component/chart/fixscripts?task=';

constructor(private http: Http) {}

getUsers(): Observable<User[]> {
    return this.http
        .get(this.usersUrl+'getUsers')
        .map((r: Response) => r.json().data);
}

getUser(id: number): Observable<User> {
    return this.http
        .get(this.usersUrl+'getUser&id='+id)
        .map((r: Response) => r.json().data);
}

saveUser(user: User): Observable<User> {
    let body = JSON.stringify(user);
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return this.http
        .post(this.usersUrl+'saveUser', body, options)
        .map((r: Response) => r.json().data);
}
}
```

Service returns necessary data (it is shown in console), but it isn't written to property

Comment: add service code please.

Comment: not really related to your question but you shouldn't be making service call from inside your constructors.

Comment: I've tried to make call from ngOnInit(){}. Result is the same

Comment: i've got it! It's needed some time for my service to return data. And when template tries to use property, it doesn't exist yet.
Is there some way say to angular wait for ngOnInit method finish?

Comment: If it's interesting for somebody, I found some way to solve this problem. I wraped whole template  with an *ngIf="user". If somebody knows a better way, please write here

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing some error handling in your service.

```
   getUser(id: number): Observable<User> {
        return this.http
            .get(this.usersUrl+'getUser&id='+id)
            .map((r: Response) => r.json().data)
            .catch(error => this.onError(error)); <!-- NEW -->
    }

    onError(error: any) {

        //Log error?

        let errMsg = error.message || 'Server error';
        console.error(errMsg);
        return Observable.throw(errMsg);
    }
```

Comment: ok. But there is no error. getUser method return right observable